# Analogue of ||= operator in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a map `event` and I want to assign default value to one of its keys if it's blank. How can I do that?

In ruby we have `event[:done] ||= value` for hashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map.put_new(event, :key, "value")
```